# Python type casting

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I try to iterate over some number using Python 3. To do so I thought about casting the number to string. Simplified version is here:

```
def printValue(num):
    value = str(num)
    for i in len(value):
        print(value[i])
    return;
```

However though I get info that int is not iterable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                             
    print(printValue(12112121))                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "main.py", line 5, in printValue
    for i in len(value):                                                                                                                                                                                                          
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Python doesn't have type casting (which is the process of telling the compiler to treat a value with one type as having another type). `str(num)` creates a brand new value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`len` returns an integer, and you can't iterate over an integer.

If you want to iterate over the range of integers from 0 up to `len(value)`, use `range`.

```
for i in range(len(value)):
```

Although in this case you don't really need the indices, so you may as well just iterate directly over the string's characters.

```
for c in value:
```

Comment: I want to get each number of integer separately for some reason.

Comment: Ok, and iterating in the manner I described lets you do that. Are you still having problems?

Comment: Still it treats value as an int and claims I cannot iterate through it.

Comment: Works now. My mistake (as always) - I missed "range" part. Thank you :)